What are the possible modifications I need to do to simulate real user traffic for a given web URL?
I was running my selenium script on a hosted cloud server to simulate and increase the real user count.
Unfortunately at the beginning of the day it shows a lot of user count at my web admin dashboard.
But at the end of the day it all will reduce to a lesser number of user count.
So what are the possible options I have to do to simulate real user traffic for a given web URL?
This is how I start the webdriver:
 chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
                //chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
                chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
                chromeOptions.addArguments("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");
                chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");

                chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
                chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
                driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

                Dimension dimension = new Dimension(2400, 1400);
                driver.manage().window().setSize(dimension);


For what purpose? Are you trying to do load/performance testing? If so, Selenium is not the right tool for that!

Hi @LeeJensen not at all. This is just to increase the visitor count on my website.
